# Using rx to subscribe to event and perform logging after time interval

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a simple use case where:

1. Receive a notification of events
2. Perform some action on the event
3. Print the content after x interval

How can I do the above step in a single Rx pipeline?

Something like below:

```
void Main()
{
    var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    // Receive event and call Foo()
    observable.Subscribe(x=>Foo());
    // After 1 minute, I want to print the result of count
    // How do I do this using above observable?
}

int count = 0;
void Foo()
{
    Console.Write(".");
    count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Do(x => Foo())
        .Window(() => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0)));

var subscription =
    observable
        .Subscribe(xs => Console.WriteLine(count));
```

However, it's a bad idea to mix state with observables. If you had two subscriptions you'd increment `count` twice as fast. It's better to encapsulate your state within the observable so that each subscription would get a new instance of `count`.

Try this instead:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var count = 0;
            return
                Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                    .Select(x =>
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                        return ++count;
                    });
        })
        .Window(() => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1)))
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.LastAsync());

var subscription =
    observable
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

I get this kind of output:

```
...........................................................59
............................................................119
............................................................179
............................................................239
```

Remembering that it starts with 0 then this is timing pretty well.

---

After seeing paulpdaniels answer I realized that I could replace my `Window`/`SelectMany`/`LastAsync` with the simpler `Sample` operator.

Also, if we don't really need the side-effect of incrementing a counter then this whole observable shrinks down to this:

```
var observable =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Do(x => Console.Write("."))
        .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));

observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Much simpler!

Comment: Yes you are correct about the multiple subscription problem and that has to be addressed. @paulpdaniels reply is also very useful. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Select` + `Sample`:

```
var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .Select((x, i) => {
            Foo(x);
            return i;
          })
          .Do(_ => Console.Write("."))
          .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

`Select` has an overload that returns the index of the current value, by returning that and then sampling at 1 minute intervals, you can get the last value emitted during that interval.